# How to convert sql output to Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a Dataframe, from which a create a temporary view in order to run sql queries. After a couple of sql queries, I'd like to convert the output of sql query to a new Dataframe. The reason I want data back in Dataframe is so that I can save it to blob storage.

So, the question is: what is the proper way to convert sql query output to Dataframe?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
%scala
//read data from Azure blob
...
var df = spark.read.parquet(some_path)

// create temp view
df.createOrReplaceTempView("data_sample")

%sql
//have some sqlqueries, the one below is just an example
SELECT
   date,
   count(*) as cnt
FROM
   data_sample
GROUP BY
   date

//Now I want to have a dataframe  that has the above sql output. How to do that?
Preferably the code would be in python or scala.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Scala:

```
var df = spark.sql(s"""
SELECT
   date,
   count(*) as cnt
FROM
   data_sample
GROUP BY
   date
""")
```

#### PySpark:

```
df = spark.sql(f'''
SELECT
   date,
   count(*) as cnt
FROM
   data_sample
GROUP BY
   date
''')
```

Comment: Can the sql string be parametrized? Something like f’’’ SELECT date + {timezone} as date, … ‘’’ where timezone is a parameter?

Comment: yes, like f'''SELECT date, {timezone} from ... '''

Comment: in PySpark: ```table = 'schema.my_table'``` ```df = spark.sql(f'''select * from {table}''')```

Answer (score 0):

You can create temporary view in %%sql code, and then reference it from pyspark or scala code like this:

```
%sql
create temporary view sql_result as
SELECT ...

%scala
var df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM sql_result")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since May 2022nd, results of SQL queries in the notebooks are available as `_sqldf` variable that is corresponding DataFrame object accessible from Python code. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/notebooks-code#--explore-sql-cell-results-in-python-notebooks-natively-using-python) for more details & description of behavior.